# when i type ionic cordova build android

Tags: android, linux, ionic-framework

th ionic info
global packages:

```
@ionic/cli-utils : 1.0.0
Cordova CLI      : 7.0.1 
Ionic CLI        : 3.0.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova : 1.0.0
@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic1  : 1.0.0
Ionic Framework           : ionic1 1.3.3
```

System:

```
Node       : v7.9.0
OS         : Linux 4.4
Xcode      : not installed
ios-deploy : not installed
ios-sim    : not installed
```

✖ Running command - failed!

[ERROR] Cordova encountered an error.
        You may get more insight by running the Cordova command above directly.

[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova build android (exit code 1):

```
    Running command: /home/mohamed/Bureau/IonicApp/PFE/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js /home/mohamed/Bureau/IonicApp/PFE
    ANDROID_HOME=/home/mohamed/Android/Sdk
    JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_131
    Subproject Path: CordovaLib
    The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use Task.doLast(Action) instead.
        at build_5epix5or8n8ltg7s8l8l2lith.run(/home/mohamed/Bureau/IonicApp/PFE/platforms/android/build.gradle:137)
    The JavaCompile.setDependencyCacheDir() method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 4.0.
    Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
    The TaskInputs.source(Object) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 4.0. Please use TaskInputs.file(Object).skipWhenEmpty() instead.
    :preBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :checkDebugManifest
    :CordovaLib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest
    :CordovaLib:prepareDebugDependencies
    :CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:compileLint UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:copyDebugLint UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:mergeDebugProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:processDebugResources/home/mohamed/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.3/aapt: 3: /home/mohamed/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.3/aapt: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string

     FAILED

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:processDebugResources'.
    > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

    BUILD FAILED

    Total time: 1.848 secs
    Error: /home/mohamed/Bureau/IonicApp/PFE/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
    /home/mohamed/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.3/aapt: 3: /home/mohamed/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.3/aapt: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

```
    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:processDebugResources'.
    > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Answer (score 0):

Please update the local packages and the global package to the latest versions and try again.
global packages:

```
@ionic/cli-utils : 1.3.0
Cordova CLI      : 7.0.1
Ionic CLI        : 3.3.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts              : 1.3.0
@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.2.1
@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.2.0
Cordova Platforms               : android 6.1.2
Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 3.0.1
```

System:

```
Node       : v6.10.2
OS         : Windows 7
Xcode      : not installed
ios-deploy : not installed
ios-sim    : not installed
```